# Стартовая позиция полосы прокрутки в panel

Tags: c#, winforms, прокрутка

Имеется панель на которой размещены элементы. С помощью кода ниже удалось добавить вертикальную полосу прокрутки (выглядит то оно так, но мы все понимаем что это просто autoscroll). Вопрос, как задать стартовую позицию, что бы при нажатии на кнопку ползунок переместился в самый верх.

*Код для вертикальной полосы*

```
panel1.AutoScroll = false;
panel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

Думал сработает что по типу `panel1.SelectionStart = 1;` , но увы.

Comment: Почему код для вертикальной полосы содержит только настройки горизонтальной?

Comment: Он отключает горизонтальную полосу и начинает работать вертикальная (предварительно отключается автоскролл, что бы код вообще сработал). Код не мой, но он работает. 
Сам не понимаю почему нельзя было докучи добавить VerticalScroll, но разработчики Windows Forms решили наверно, что кому оно понадобится оставим только HorizontalScroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать положение полосы прокрутки можно так

В начало

```cs
panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
```

В конец

```cs
panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum);
```

Comment: Благодарю, код работает.